# R devtools::install_github("jzsbioinfo/APRD") Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,

Tags: r, github, installation

R devtools::install_github("jzsbioinfo/APRD") Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet, : Can not open URL'https://api.github.com/repos/jzsbioinfo/APRD/tarball/master'

My session info:

```
─ Session info ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
setting value
version R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
os Windows 10 x64
system x86_64, mingw32
ui RStudio
language (EN)
```

Methods I have tried but doesn't work:

```
options(download.file.method = "libcurl")
devtools::install_github("jzsbioinfo/APRD")
```

or

```
options(download.file.method = "wininet")
devtools::install_github("jzsbioinfo/APRD")
```

I also tried to check the Use TLS 1.2 box in the internet opinions, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

the problem has been solved. I just updated devtools and remotes package.