# devtools::install_github failing in R4.0.03

Tags: r, devtools

I upgraded recently to R4.0.3 and devtools::install_github no longer seems to work. E.g..

```
> install_github('MacoskoLab/liger')
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo MacoskoLab/liger@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/MacoskoLab/liger/tarball/HEAD' failed
```

or

```
install_github("NathanSkene/MAGMA_Celltyping")
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo NathanSkene/MAGMA_Celltyping@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/NathanSkene/MAGMA_Celltyping/tarball/HEAD' failed
```

Not entirely clear to me whether it's devtools, or utils::download.file or R itself that's gone haywire here. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Have you updated package `devtools`?

Comment: with `devtools ‘2.3.2’` works

Comment: I've installed devtools 2.3.2 and still have the same error

Comment: Same issue was reported here: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2303. Issue was suggested to be ` install.packages("remotes")` but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Here it's being discussed that it's related to github deciding they find the word 'master' problematic: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2237

Comment: In this issue it's been noted that the issue can be reproduced: https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/573. One person was able to resolve it by installing the dev version of remotes.

Comment: Someone noted related issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273115/r-devtoolsinstall-githubjzsbioinfo-aprd-error-in-utilsdownload-fileurl?rq=1) but could resolve this by updating devtools + remotes which doesn't fix it on my machine

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that this problem was caused by the download timing out. The repository in question is quite large (it contains datasets as well as code). There is a default 60 second timeout for install_github. Increasing this made it work:

```
options(timeout=9999999)
install_github("NathanSkene/MAGMA_Celltyping")
```